# How can I declare an ILogger<subclass> in the base class?

Tags: c#, generics, blazor-server-side

This is in Blazor server although I think that's irrelevant here.

I have a base class where I primarily declare the [Inject] services all my razor pages need. So a lot of:

```
[Inject] 
protected IDbContextFactory<NoTrackingDbContext> NoTrackingDbFactory { get; set; } = default!;

[Inject]
protected ExUserManager UserManager { get; set; } = default!;

[Inject]
protected NavigationManager Navigation { get; set; } = default!;
```

I'd like to also have in it:

```
[Inject]
private ScopedLoggerFactory<T> ScopedLoggerFactory { get; set; } = default!;

protected ScopedLogger<T> Logger { get; set; } = default!;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
        Logger = ScopedLoggerFactory.GetLogger(Principal);
}
```

Where `<T>` is the subclass inheriting from it. I tried declaring the base class as:

```
ExPageBase<T> : where T is class
```

And then the razor file as

```
Interests : ExPageBase<Interest>
```

but the compiler did not like that.

At present what I do in every subclass (and granted, it's not a big deal so the present situation is fine) is:

```
[Inject]
private ScopedLoggerFactory<Interests> ScopedLoggerFactory { get; set; } = default!;

private ScopedLogger<Interests> Logger { get; set; } = default!;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Logger = ScopedLoggerFactory.GetLogger(Principal);
}
```

Is there a way to move that bit of 2 member declarations and the assignment into the base class?

Comment: Are you trying to associate the user with log messages? In that case it's probably better to inject `ILoggerFactory`, create a new logger with `_logFactory.Create(this.GetType())` and use `BeginScope` to associate the user with the scope. That scope will have to be disposed in the component's `Dispose`. It seems the problem is the use of generic. `ILoggerFactory.Create` has a non-generic overload that accepts `Type`

Comment: If ILoggerFactory can't be used (why?), a non-generic `CreateLogger` should be added to `ScopedLoggerFactory`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think both of those proposed solutions have to be in the subclass. That doesn't get me what I want. I already have an easy solution in the subclass - I just declare the first with [Inject] and then instantiate the second. What I'm trying to accomplish is eliminate that. Or did I not understand your comments?

Comment: `Create(this.GetType())` doesn't have to be in the subclass. The type returned is the actual type ie the child. The child class will have to call the base `Dispose()` to allow it to dispose the context

Comment: Shouldn't `private ScopedLogger<Interests> Logger ` be *protected* to allow child components to use the logger?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry - yes. The #1 source of bugs - copy & paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can do it simplier** - no need to use generic type parameter `<T>` for your `Blazor` components if you use `ILogger` this way:

```
namespace MyNameSpace.Components
{
    public abstract class MyComponent : ComponentBase
    {
        [Inject] private ILoggerFactory LoggerFactory { get; set; } = default!;
        protected ILogger Logger1 => LoggerFactory.CreateLogger(GetType());
        protected ILogger Logger2 => LoggerFactory.CreateLogger("Any Category Name");
    }
}

namespace MyNameSpace.Pages
{
    public class MyPage : MyNameSpace.Components.MyComponent
    {
        protected override void OnParametersSet()
        {
            string message = $"Hello from {nameof(MyPage)}!";

            Logger1.LogDebug(message); // Gives you "MyNameSpace.Pages.MyPage[0] Hello from MyPage!"

            Logger2.LogDebug(message); // Gives you "Any Category Name Hello from MyPage!" 
        }
    }
}
```

Documentation: [ASP.NET Core Blazor logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/logging)

Comment: Sometimes the answers is so blindingly obvious - only after someone points it out. Kicking myself for not thinking of this. Thank you **very** much.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `where T : class` try this generic constraint:

```cs
public abstract class ExPageBase<T> where T : ExPageBase<T>
{
    [Inject]
    private ScopedLoggerFactory<T> ScopedLoggerFactory { get; set; } = default!;

    protected ScopedLogger<T> Logger { get; set; } = default!;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Logger = ScopedLoggerFactory.GetLogger(Principal);
    }
}
```

This way you can access the protected members in the derived class, e.g. `Interests`.

## Update #1:

I tried the following with a Blazor server app project and according to the log entries it works well:

I created the base class.

**ExPageBase**

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace BlazorApp1.Pages;

public partial class ExPageBase<T> : ComponentBase
    where T : ExPageBase<T>
{
    [Inject]
    public ILogger<T> Logger { get; set; } = default!;

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("Component initialized in the base class.");
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

Then I updated the `Counter.razor` page:

```
@page "/counter"
<!-- Tell the Counter component the derive from our base class. -->
@inherits ExPageBase<Counter>

<!-- rest omitted for clarity -->
```

Then I created a partial class to the `Counter.razor` page:

**Counter.cs**

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace BlazorApp1.Pages;

public partial class Counter
{
    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("Component initialized in the derived class.");
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

Then in the console window these log events appeared:

```bash
info: BlazorApp1.Pages.Counter[0]
      Component initialized in the derived class.
info: BlazorApp1.Pages.Counter[0]
      Component initialized in the base class.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That looks great and so I tried it and... changing it to that base class my razor file inheriting it no longer is a razor component. It's not viewed as a render tree component. Any idea what's going on with that? TIA

Comment: @DavidThielen, I updated my answer. In my example code I think that the fact that the `ExPageBase<T>` class derives from the `ComponentBase` class does the trick. Then simply add the `@inherits` statement to your razor page and it should work. And also you can simply inject `ILogger<T>` where `T` will be your component's type. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried numerous variations of what you listed. No luck. That's ok, not a biggie.